# Create Azure Objects Using 'Publish Settings' File

Tags: azure, powershell

So, I'm told if you import your `Azure Subscription Publish Setting` file into `PowerShell`...you can use the certificate in the `Publish Setting` file to create objects in your `Azure Subscription`.

However, I am getting the following exception trying to create a `Resource Group`:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroup : Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.
> + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroup], PSInvalidOperationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupCmdlet

I Do The Following In My Script:

- "Import" the Subscription
- "Select" the Subscription
- "Get" the Subscription (to view it)

...the subscription is both "Default & Current" (see attached image).
...and yet I still get that message.

**SAMPLE CODE:**
This code is edited so as not to "give away the farm"...

```
#Set Subscription
$Subscription_Id = "<not shown>"

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId  $Subscription_Id
Get-AzureSubscription

# CHECK EXISTS: ResourceGroup
$RegionFullName = "South Central US"

$RegionShortName = "scus"
$EnvironmentShortName = "dev"
$ApplicationShortName = "<not shown>"
$ObjectTypeShortName = "rg"

$ResourceGroupFullName = "$($RegionShortName)-$($EnvironmentShortName)-$($ApplicationShortName)-$($ObjectTypeShortName)"

$ResourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupFullName -ErrorVariable NotPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($ResourceGroup -eq $Null) {

    #CREATE: ResourceGroup
    $ResourceGroup = New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupFullName -Location $RegionFullName -Confirm
}
```

[image: Exception Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using `Import-PublishSettingsFile`, but Azure Management Certificates and Publishing Setting files are only intended (for) and (are) limited to managing `Azure Service Management (ASM)` resources, [which are being retired](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-automation-service-management-rest-apis-are-being-retired-april-30-2019/).

In your script, you mixed the [`ASM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/overview?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) and [`AzureRm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/overview?view=azurermps-6.13.0) powershell modules together. `Select-AzureSubscription` and `Get-AzureSubscription` belong to `ASM`, `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` and `New-AzureRmResourceGroup` belong to `AzureRm`.

So if you need to use `AzureRm` command, you need to run `Connect-AzureRmAccount` to login your account.

Comment: FYI ... AZURE RM is now considered outdated.  We now must use AZ POWERSHELL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-5.2.0